# What's the advantage of ASP.NET Web API to ASP.NET MVC Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, compare

What's the advantage of ASP.NET Web API to ASP.NET MVC Controller?

As far as I know, IIS + WebDAV conflicts with ASP.NET Web API while using "PUT" verb[1].

We can use ASP.NET MVC Controller & JsonResult, etc. to communicate with clients, which use HTTP GET+POST and no more verb to get better compatibility, so what's the advantage of ASP.NET Web API to ASP.NET MVC?

And, ASP.NET Web API should only use the desigend teens HTTP verbs. If I'd like to develop a Web API to let a robot **JUMP**, but **JUMP** is not a standard HTTP verb. So how to design the url? `http://localhost/api/robot/jump` ? But it is not RESTful(RESTful urls should not contain verb).

reference:
[1] http://forums.iis.net/t/1163441.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about the difference between Asp.Net application .cs files and controllers in MVC.

1. We can navigate to required method in MVC depending upon requirement but this is not possible in Asp.Net web.
2. Always, firing the page load event will not happen.
3. We can return partial results/Json results/Javascript results and so on.

Unlike Asp.Net life cycle, MVC has its own page life cycle.

Regards,
Pavan.G

Comment: But My question is about ASP.NET Web API ( http://www.asp.net/web-api ) and ASP.NET MVC.